# Java do while loop arralyist problem

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I want ask why Java heap space is triggered when executing "`NAME.add("Tom");`"?

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>

<%
try {
    ArrayList <String> NAME = new ArrayList<String>();
    int count= 0;

    do
    {
        NAME.add("Tom");
    } while ( count < 2);

    String[] name = NAME.toArray(new String[NAME.size()]);

%>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var output=[];
    <%int i = 0;%>

    <%while ( i < name.length ) { System.out.println(name[i]);%>
        output[<%=i%>] = [];
        output[<%=i%>][0] = '<%=name[i]%>';

    <% System.out.println("No exception in JAVASCRIPT.");i++;}%>
</script>

<%
} catch (Exception error ){System.out.println(error);}%>
```

Answer (score 3):

Notice that in this code:

```
int count= 0;

do
{
    NAME.add("Tom");
} while ( count < 2);
```

You never change the value of `count` anywhere, and so this loop will loop forever.  If you change the code so that you change `count` somehow (perhaps by using a `for` loop to count upwards), this should go away.  The JVM is probably running out of heap space by adding as many copies of `Tom` as it can to the collection, eventually exhausting available memory.

Comment: The list will not really contain copies of `"Tom"`, only many, many references to the same `"Tom"` object. Still, each of this reference takes 4 (or 8) bytes, and they eventually will fill the heap.

Answer (score 1):

You're not incrementing the `count` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code

> int count= 0;
>       do
>       {
>           NAME.add("Tom");
>          } while ( count < 2);

You forget to increment `count`. So in your code, it will do an infinite loop and all your memory will be taken.